# Add JButtons to JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I want to add a number of `JButtons` to a `JPanel` using a `For` loop. When the user presses a button, the following code is run:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  JButton aButton = new JButton();
  mainPanel.add(aButton);
  mainPanel.revalidate();
  mainPanel.repaint();
  System.out.println("Added: " + (i + 1) + "buttons");
}
```

However, when I press the button, no JButtons are added to the JPanel, but the program prints the appropriate number of buttons that should be added.

Not sure what the problem is here =/

Comment: What layout manager are you using?

Comment: Try `invalidate` instead of `revalidate` and `repaint` - and is there any reason you can't just do that at the end of the loop?

Comment: You should not validate and repaint your panel each time that you add a button, but only after having added all your buttons. Validating and painting a GUI window is generally costly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem. I'm using NetBeans and apparently Free Layout doesn't work, so I set the JPanel's layout to Grid Layout and voila, the buttons appear

Comment: You still don't want to be calling the repaint method inside the for loop. There is no reason to repaint the panel ten times.

Comment: Thanks. Will repaint outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    mainPanel.add(new JButton("Button text"));
    System.out.println("Added: " + (i + 1) + "buttons");
}

mainPanel.invalidate();
mainPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: if you need invalidate and repaint you are most likely doing something wrong?

Comment: All you need is revalidate(). This will cause the layout manager to be invoked.